# Storyboard reduce gap between views

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

[image]

I am working on a sample project with three views with each gap 10 vertically in storyboard.I did hide second view with below code:

```
@IBOutlet var height:NSLayoutConstraint?
  height?.constant = 0
```

gap between view1 and view3 is 20.
how do i reduce gap between view1 and view3 to 10?

Comment: Please show the code that you are using... also, is you use UIStackView this will happen for free.

Comment: i am not using UIStackview

Comment: I know. I can tell from the snippet of code you showed. That’s why I suggested to use UIStackView. It makes this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't want to use `UIStackView`, you need to play with the `constraints` of `secondView`.

Create `height, top, bottom` `constraint` `@IBOutlet` for `secondView` and update them for show/hide cases, i.e.

```
@IBOutlet weak var secondViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var secondViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var secondBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func hideSecondView(_ hide: Bool) {
    secondViewHeightConstraint.constant = hide ? 0 : 50 //used 50 as the height of secondView
    secondViewTopConstraint.constant = hide ? 10 : 20
    secondViewTopConstraint.constant = hide ? 10 : 20

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to use [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) in this case as it will do the same thing you want.

User vertical UIStackView with spacing 10. You can accomplish this either by a xib, storyboard or from a code.

Example:

```
let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [view, secondView, thirdView])
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.alignment = .fill
stackView.spacing = 10.0
```

Comment: any idea how to handle it without UIStackview?

Comment: @karthi What's the issue in using UIStackView if it more easy and manageable to use?

Comment: i have to fix this issue in a project which is done without UIStackview

Comment: @karthi fix it by using a stack view. 

Comment: You can easily fix it with the stack view. Just embed the views in the stackview and constraints for the stackview